# Converting a string of delimiter separated values that represent columns and rows into a map table

Tags: javascript

I have a string that is built up from columns and rows...

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P
```

In the case of the string above, there would be 4 columns and 4 rows (though there could be 20 columns and 5 rows.  I will always know the amount of columns and rows).

```
A E I M
B F J N
C G K O
D H L P
```

What I am trying to do, is put those into a map so that the key is the column and row so I can use it as a lookup.  So the map would look like, `A = 0_0, B = 0_1, C = 0_2, ... P = 3_3`.

Am sure it's relatively simple, but I can't seem to get it correct.

```
let str = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P";
let parts = str.split(",");
let my_map = new Map();

//... loop(s) here

console.log(my_map.get("3_3")) // P
```

Comment: You can divide length  by 2 and then loop over array and push values as `.push([i, i+len])`. You can refer following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/68b0j2vr/)

Comment: Iterate the `parts`. If `i` is in the first half of the parts, the first number in the string is `0` else `1`. The second number is just `i%(parts.length/2)`.

Comment: I've edited my question, I didn't really explain the string correctly it seems.

Comment: A couple of things spring out immediately. **(0)** Your input string has 15 elements, yet you've constructed a 4x4 block with them - has 'H' been repeated by mistake? **(1)** You're using zero-based indexing, so with 4 rows and columns, wouldn't the key that extracts 'O' in your example actually be '3_3'?

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks, kinda rushed typing up my question and overlooked those.  Have fixed those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes the input string and forms a virtual block with it, whose coords are then used as the key in a map to retrieve each element.

It's familiar code for anyone accustomed to bit-mapped graphics - with the important distinction that adjacent elements in the buffer fill columns first, rather than rows.

My example merely extracts the elements at the 4 corners of the virtual block.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 let resultMap = makeLookupMap("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P", ',', 4,4);
 console.log("Key: 0_0, Value: " + resultMap.get("0_0") );
 console.log("Key: 0_3, Value: " +  resultMap.get("0_3") );
 console.log("Key: 3_0, Value: " +  resultMap.get("3_0") );
 console.log("Key: 3_3, Value: " +  resultMap.get("3_3") );
}

function makeLookupMap(inString,delim, nCols,nRows)
{
 let stringElems = inString.split(delim); // break apart the input string
 
 if (nRows*nCols > stringElems.length)
  return undefined;      // error - not enough elements
 
 let myMap = new Map();
 
 for (var curCol=0; curCol<nCols; curCol++)
 {
  for (var curRow=0; curRow<nRows; curRow++)
  {
   let index = (curCol*nRows) + curRow;
   let curKey = curCol + '_' + curRow;
   myMap.set( curKey, stringElems[index] );
  }
 }
 return myMap;
}
```

Comment: Excellent.  Sorry I can't accept it though, I don't have enough rep (when I do, I'll come back).  Thank you.  - Edit:  Oh, I can.  Just can't vote it up.

Comment: @JacketPotatoeFan - That's okay and you're welcome. I don't care (thanks though!), I answer for the sake of solving problems - like sudoku or crosswords in which the results are actually good for something. As a bonus, everybody learns a bit here and there. The whole points thing is merely a distraction... Marking the problem as solved is plenty enough to remove it from the 'unanswered questions' queue.